# How does one get the "next" record from database sorted by a specific attribute without loading all the records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, datetime

**Here's the situation:**
I have an Event model and I want to add prev / next buttons to a view to get the next event, but sorted by the event `start` datetime, not the ID/`created_at`.

So the events are created in the order that start, so I can compare IDs or get the next highest ID or anything like that. E.g. Event ID 2 starts before Event ID 3. So `Event.next(3)` should return Event ID 2.

At first I was passing the start datetime as a param and getting the next one, but this failed when there were 2 events with the same start. The param start datetime doesn't include microseconds, so what would happen is something like this:

```
order("start > ?",current_start).first
```

would keep returning the same event over and over because `current_start` wouldn't include microseconds, so the current event would technically be `>` than `current_start` by 0.000000124 seconds or something like that.

The way I got to work for everything was with a concern like this:

```
module PrevNext
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def next(id)
      find_by(id: chron_ids[current_index(id)+1])
    end

    def prev(id)
      find_by(id: chron_ids[current_index(id)-1])
    end

    def chron_ids
      @chron_ids ||= order("#{order_by_attr} ASC").ids
    end

    def current_index(id)
      chron_ids.find_index(id)
    end

    def order_by_attr
      @order_by_attr ||= 'created_at'
    end
  end
end
```

Model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  include PrevNext

  def self.order_by_attr
    @order_by_attr ||= "start_datetime"
  end

  ...
end
```

**I know pulling all the IDs into an array is bad and dumb*** but i don't know how to

1. Get a list of the records in the order I want
2. Jump to a specific record in that list (current event)
3. and then get the next record

...all in one ActiveRecord query. (Using Rails 4 w/ PostgreSQL)

*This table will likely never have more than 10k records, so it's not catastrophically bad and dumb.

The best I could manage was to pull out only the IDs in order and then memoize them.

Ideally, i'd like to do this by just passing the Event ID, rather than a start date params, since it's passed via GET param, so the less URL encoding and decoding the better.

There has to be a better way to do this. I posted it on Reddit as well, but the only suggested response didn't actually work.

- [Reddit Link](https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/5599ua/code_reviewfeedback_i_wrote_a_module_that_will/)

Any help or insight is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the next `n` records by using the SQL [OFFSET keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/queries-limit.html):

```
china = Country.order(:population).first
india = City.order(:population).offset(1).take
# SELECT * FROM countries ORDER BY population LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

Which is how pagination for example often is done:

```
@countries = Country.order(:population).limit(50)
@countries = scope.offset( params[:page].to_i * 50 ) if params[:page]
```

Another way to do this is by using would be [query cursors](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/03/30/five-ways-to-paginate/). However ActiveRecord does not support this and it building a generally reusable solution would be quite a task and may not be very useful in the end.